# WP_Query which includes custom meta fields of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Below is the code which I have written to WP_Query a bunch of filters which involves post's custom meta fields,

```
        <?php
            global $post;
            $month=date("m", time());    //current month
            $month=intval($month);       //converting '03' to int 3
            $args = array( 'meta_key'=>"city", 'meta_value'=>'NY',   'numberposts' => 100, 
'cat'=>"read", "monthnum" => $month, 'post_status' =>  "publish", 
'order'=>"ASC", "orderby" => "meta_value_num", "meta_key" => "article_order");      
            $posts = WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
```

What I want to achieve from the above query is, " select this month's published posts from 'read' category with meta key 'city' having value 'NY' and order by 'meta_value_num' of meta_key 'article_order' "

Comment: Put `city` in quotes `'city'`. And also tell us what is not working ?  Do you have such post ? Does it not fetching it ?

Comment: @Rikesh  $args = array('numberposts' => 100, 
'category'=>2, 'post_status' =>  "publish", 
'order'=>"ASC", "orderby" => "meta_value_num", "meta_key" => "article_order");      //is working
            $posts = get_posts( $args ); //when i put get_posts.  <br /> This code is working. When I put 'meta_key'=>"city", 'meta_value'=>'NY', and 'cat'=>"read", "monthnum" => $month to WP_Query Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

may be try some thing like

```
<?php
            global $post;
            $month=date("m", time());    //current month
            $month=intval($month);       //converting '03' to int 3
            $args = array( 'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 'NY',
        )
    ), 'numberposts' => 100, 
'cat'=>"read", "monthnum" => $month, 'post_status' =>  "publish", 
'order'=>"ASC", "orderby" => "meta_value_num", "meta_key" => "article_order");      
            $posts = WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
```

hope this work and also in your code you are missing '' in your `'meta_key'=>city` as `'meta_key'=>'city'`

hope this work for you

Comment: Thanks @anstrangel0ver I have not tried this yet. If it works, then I will come back and accept your answer.

Comment: ya surely may be i juss read your above comment it may be something interesting if my code is not working